# How do I add a script bundle conditionally?

Tags: bundle, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a javascript bundle that I only want to include when testing, not when the code is deployed to production.

I have added a Property called `IsEnabledTestingFeatures`. In the BundleConfig.cs file I access it like so:

```
if(Properties.Settings.Default.IsEnabledTestingFeatures) {
    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/testing").Include("~/Scripts/set-date.js"));
}
```

This works correctly.

Now, I only want to *include* the bundle in my page if this property is set to true.

I have tried the following, but the compiler is complaining that it cannot find the `Default` namespace:

```
@{
    if( [PROJECT NAMESPACE].Properties.Default.IsEnabledTestingFeatures)
    {
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/testing")
    }
}
```

I tried finding how to access the `Scripts.Render` functionality from the Controller itself, but have been unsuccessful.

I prefer to add the bundle in the view itself, but will settle for adding it via the Controller.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Until, hopefully, an alternative [read: better] solution is proposed, I have implemented it using ViewBag.

**BundleConfig.cs**

```
//if testing features are enabled (eg: "Set Date"), include the necessary scripts
if(Properties.Settings.Default.IsEnabledTestingFeatures)
{
    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/testing").Include(
        "~/Scripts/set-date.js"));
}
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.IsEnabledTestingFeatures = Properties.Settings.Default.IsEnabledTestingFeatures;
    return View();
}
```

**View**

```
@if (ViewBag.IsEnabledTestingFeatures != null && ViewBag.IsEnabledTestingFeatures)
{
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/site")
}
```

Some Notes:

1. I did not implement this via a property in the ViewModel due to this
   property/feature being independent of the data being displayed. It
   seemed incorrect to associate this condition with individual data
   models as it is a site-wide feature.
2. I used application-level settings because it will be easier to configure this property on a per-environment basis due to the fact we utilize web transforms. Thus each environment can set this property as needed.

Answer (score 10):

The `ViewBag` should not be necessary...

Using `appSettings` from *web.config* you don't need to recompile for testing and it deploys easily.

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="TestingEnabled" value="true" />
</appSettings>
```

**View or Layout**

```
@{
    bool testing = Convert.ToBoolean(
        System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TestingEnabled"]);
}

@if (testing) {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/testing")
}
```

And I would define `"~/bundles/testing"` in `BundleConfig` regardless of the testing condition unless you wish to bundle this with other scripts.

If you assigned `Properties.Default.IsEnabledTestingFeatures` from AppSettings then the root of your problem is how you implemented your Properties.

Comment: Wish I could up-vote more than once! This should definitely be the accepted answer. (IMHO)